# Latest Sygic Android Sdk version

Tags: sygic-mobile-sdk

I am trying to integrate the sygic mobile sdk for android. 
I am following this [guide](https://www.sygic.com/developers/mobile-sdk/android/getting-started).

It says to add this configuration to the build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation("com.sygic.sdk:sdk-release:$sygicSdkVersion@aar") {
    transitive true
}}
```

The guide says that the *sygicSdkVersion* is indicated in the release notes section which unfortunately appears to be empty. 
Any help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently the latest public version is `2.12.8`. Sorry abuout the shortcomings in the guide as it is still evolving.

Comment: Unable to download given version: implementation 'com.sygic.sdk:sdk-release:2.12.8@aar'